# How to detect the state of an app other than mine?

Tags: android, application-state

I have looked around, but all suggestions are for checking state of my own app/activity.
using the Life Cycle.
I need to check if another app is in foreground/ running in background / paused . 
Is it possible. Based on the state of the app i need to change my further actions.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Comment: may i know why you want to do this? what action you will do?

Comment: @kumaand i have a broadcast receiver that tracks incomming sms, and makes updates to db. If the app is in foreground i also need to update GUI for the app.

Comment: Send Notification from broadcast receiver, Send the pending intent from notification and update the UI

Comment: @kumaand That will only make the user to call update, i found a diff method from the suggestion of Ali Imran above.I posting it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActivityManager acm=(ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = acm.getRunningTasks(1); 
taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
String packageName=componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

I used Activity manager to find the top package / activity  if this matches the requrements i send a broadcast to the app that will update the info from the db. This can simply be done by registering a broadcast receiver using code in the onResume and Unregister it in OnPause.
So checking the Top package has just become a double check.

Comment: Thank you , I just added a for loop in my service and checked for all running apps  , if the package name exists in the list , then the app is running , I used this to display notification if the app is closed or floating window if the app is running.... Thanks again